Issue with SARIMA model for PM10 concentration forecasting with m=365
I'm trying to build a SARIMA (Seasonal Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average) model for forecasting PM10 concentrations based on five years of data. However, when I set the seasonal parameter m to 365, my code doesn't seem to run.
Could someone please explain why my code is not running with m=365 and suggest a potential solution?
Thanks in advance!
# Here's a snippet of my code:
## Split the dataset into train and test sets

    `train_size = int(len(Alipur_df) * 0.8)  # 80% train, 20% test`
    `train, test = Alipur_df[:train_size], Alipur_df[train_size:]`

## Convert train DataFrame to a numpy array

    `train_values = train['Alipur'].values`
    `test_values = test['Alipur'].values`

## Use auto_arima to find the best parameters for SARIMA

    `auto_model = auto_arima(train['Alipur'], seasonal=True, stationary=True, m= 365, trac


Hi. Welcome to CV. This is more of programming-issue question rather than a statistical one. So, this would be better at Stack Overflow.

@User1865345: to a degree, you have a point. To a different degree, this is at the intersection between stats and programming, because one of the main reasons why "long seasonality" SARIMA is not implemented is because it is intrinsically/statistically hard.

Sure @StephanKolassa. Always good when others chip in. This was my initial take as OP formatted the post that way. However, the way you frame it is definitely relevant.

SARIMA (and Exponential Smoothing) have well-known issues with "long" seasonality, as noted in Rob Hyndman's blog post:

[...] seasonal differencing of very high order does not make a lot of sense — for daily data it involves comparing what happened today with what happened exactly a year ago and there is no constraint that the seasonal pattern is smooth.

The commonly accepted way of dealing with "long" seasonality is to either use a regression on Fourier terms with ARIMA errors, or to use specialized state space models like BATS/TBATS - refer to the above linked blog post.

Does the OP force seasonal differencing? If not, the quote above is not necessarily relevant. The bigger issue (one that is orthogonal to differencing) is computational, and that is the problem the OP seems to be facing, so a quote on that could be more helpful.

@RichardHardy: we don't know whether the OP forces this. "My code does not run" is indeed not very informative, and we might have asked for more information before I answered. But I do think this aspect is relevant. YMMV.

Let me clarify. My undertstanding is that seasonal ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q) models with a long seasonal period are hard to estimate, and this is the likely reason for why "the code does not run". It is also my understanding that this has nothing to do with the values of d and D, and it applies to the case of d=D=0. Meanwhile, seasonal ARIMA models with short seasonal periods and d>1 or D>1 or both are not subject to this problem. Thus I believe your answer addresses an irrelevant issue while missing the relevant one.

I would say that the key issue for why this is not implemented is that the validity of estimating a $\phi_{365}$ AR parameter, but not $\phi_{364}$ or $\phi_{366}$ (implicitly regularizing/sparsifying exactly these to zero) is highly doubtful (so: a statistical point), which is the last two thirds of the quote. It may be that casting this in terms of seasonal differencing is not the best way to put it. Since the specific point of the differencing is not my main issue, I still believe this addresses the issue at hand.

I do not find this convincing, but thank you for taking the time to explain it to me.

Hi, many thanks to you guys for the replies. I am new to statistical forecasting and still learning. I feel the problem lies in choosing the value of m=365. I decided the value of m based on its definition: m refers to the number of periods in each season (alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/…). I did seasonal decomposition using STL which showed a seasonality of 365 days only, that's why I used it. I didn't know that value of m is restricted in SARIMA. Whenever I try to run this code, it shows a runtime error.

CV has resources for forecasting here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/559908/1352. We discuss "long" seasonality here: https://dfep.netlify.app/sec-multiple-seasaonality, which is in spirit very close to Rob Hyndman's blog post.

According to Rob Hyndman's blog post "Forecasting with long seasonal periods", seasonal ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q) models with a long seasonal period are hard to estimate:

The arima() function will allow a seasonal period up to m=350 but in practice will usually run out of memory whenever the seasonal period is more than about 200.

This is likely the reason for why your code does not run.
Contrary to the answer by Stephan Kolassa, it is my understanding that this has nothing to do with the order of seasonal differencing, D, as the problem exists not only when D>1 but also when D=0. Meanwhile, seasonal ARIMA models with short seasonal periods and D>1 are not subject to this problem. Thus, I believe the focus on seasonal differencing is a red herring.
Regarding recommended alternatives, I concur with the ones suggested in the answer by Stephan Kolassa.
